# jQuery append to div from radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, append

When a user double clicks on an image, I want to append to a nearby div (imageSelection), the filename or the alt attribute value. Right now when I double click on an image, nothing happens, so I think I have my code wrong, but not sure where.

```js
    $(document).on('dblclick', 'img', function () {
      var imgurl = window.location.pathname + $(this).attr('src');
      window.open(imgurl, '_blank');
    });
    
    $("input[name=imageselect]:radio").click(function () {
      var imgurl = window.location.pathname + $(this).attr('src');
      var $imageSelection = $('#image_selection');
      
      if ($('input[name=imageselect]:checked').val() == "filename") {
        var varsrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $imageSelection.append(varscrc);
      } else {
        var varalt = $(this).attr('alt');
        $imageSelection.append(varalt);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio_images">
    File Name   <input type="radio" name="imageselect" value="filename"> <br>
    Description  <input type="radio" name="imageselect" value="description" checked>  <br>
    </div>
    
    <div id ="imageSelection">
    </div>
    
    <div id="images">
    <h3>Some Images</h3>
     <p><img src="firetruck.jpg" alt="pic of truck">  |
     <img src="baseball.jpg" alt="pic of baseball" >  |
     <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" alt="pic of soccer ball" >
     </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you had a typo in your `imageSelection` id and you needed to change your `.click` function, so that the append would happen when you clicked the image and not the radio input. You can find the changes in the following snippet.

```js
$(document).on('dblclick', 'img', function () {
  var imgurl = window.location.pathname + $(this).attr('src');
  window.open(imgurl, '_blank');
});

$("img").click(function () {
  var imgurl = window.location.pathname + $(this).attr('src');
  var imageSelection = $('#imageSelection');

  if ($('input[name=imageselect]:checked').val() === "filename") {
    var varsrc = $(this).attr('src');
    imageSelection.append(varsrc);
  } else {
    var varalt = $(this).attr('alt');
    imageSelection.append(varalt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="radio_images">
File Name   <input type="radio" name="imageselect" value="filename">    <br>
Description  <input type="radio" name="imageselect" value="description" checked>    <br>
</div>

<div id ="imageSelection">
</div>

<div id="images">
<h3>Some Images</h3>
    <p><img src="firetruck.jpg" alt="pic of truck">  |
    <img src="baseball.jpg" alt="pic of baseball" >  |
    <img src="soccer_ball.jpg" alt="pic of soccer ball" >
    </p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.